# Is it contains either one instance if I visit http://myapp.cloudapp.net/trace.axd on the site hosted on Windows Azure?

Tags: .net, azure

It means I cannot read the trace from all instance directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your web role has two instances, and you try to navigate to \trace.axd, that request will be load balanced and sent to just one instance.  So you're correct, you can't use \trace.axd to see information from all instances of a web role.